# Relative Eigenvalue Perturbation Bound deduction from Ostrowski's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to deduce the relative eigenvalue perturbation bound from Ostrowski's Theorem. In short i need to proove ´this statement;

$\frac{|\lambda_k(SAS^*)-\lambda_k(A)|}{|\lambda_k(A)|} \leq p(I-SS^*)$

Where A, S $\in M_n$ with A Hermitian and S non-singular. Also the eigenvalues of A and SAS* are arranged in non-decreasing order. Also $\lambda_k(A)$ is a non-singular eigenvalue.

Your assistance is required.

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC&lpg=PP1&dq=matrix%20analysis%20horn&hl=cs&pg=PA283#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me at all what $p$ stands for. Is that some sort of function of $I-SS^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ostrowski's theorem
\begin{equation}
  \lambda_k(SAS^\ast)=\theta_k\lambda_k(A).
\end{equation}
So one can subtract 1 and get
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\lambda_k(A)-\lambda_k(SAS^\ast)}{\lambda_k(A)}=1-\theta_k.
\end{equation}
However, $1-\theta_k$ is an eigenvalue of $I-SS^\ast$. on the other hand, the spectral radius of $I-SS^\ast$ is defined as 
\begin{equation}
\rho(I-SS^\ast)=max\{|\lambda|\}
\end{equation}
which mean that all eigenvalues of $I-SS^\ast$ are $\leq \rho(I-SS^\ast)$.